# Possible to get reference of "operator" result?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

Is it somehow possible to get the reference of the result of an overloaded operator in C# so you don't have to use the "new" keyword to create a temp result (which is returned afterwards)?

Here's an example of a problem I ran into:

```
public class Stats {

    public float someField;
    public float someOtherField;

    public static Stats operator +(Stats a, Stats b) {
        Stats c = new Stats(); // I don't want a new one, can I access operators result directly?
        c.someField = a.someField + b.someField;
        c.someOtherField = a.someOtherField + b.someOtherField;
        return c;
    }

    /*
    // This is what I want to achieve, but it would be cooler if static and with the "+"
    public Add(SomeType a) {
        someField += a.someField;
        someOtherField += a.someOtherField
    }
    */
}

public class StatObserver {
    public Stats statsToObserve;

    public Output() {
        print(statsToObserve.someField);
    }
}

public class Class {
    public Stats firstStats = new Stats();
    firstStats.someField = 1.5f;

    public StatObserver showStats = new StatObserver();
    showStats.statsToObserve = firstStats;

    public Stats nextStats = new Stats();
    nextStats.someField = 3.4f;

    // now the tricky part
    firstStats += nextStats; // C# handles the += itself correctly

    showStats.Output(); // prints "1.5"

    // you have to update the observer to get the new value
    // it's kind of stupid, because you have to treat firstStats like a value type buts its not
    showStats.statsToObserve = firstStats;
    showStats.Output(); // prints "4.9"
}
```

Comment: So you want to essentially overload the `+=` operator?  You can;'t do that - `+=` for non-native types is compiled to a `+` and an `=`.

Comment: Are concerned about the runtime cost of dynamic allocation (correctly or not)? Then you can use structs if your data is as small as shown.

Comment: @PeterSchneider I'm pretty sure its clear thats not what he is concerned about. A good suggestion for performance critical operators, which you should never have, but if you had one, it would be good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't overload the `+=` operator directly - it is compiled to an add and an assignment.  You *could* mutate the left-hand side as part of the `+` operator - but that would be evil.  An `Add` method seems to be the cleanest design IMHO.

Comment: +1 for mutating an operand being evil. I also agree with the recommendation, though `Add` still connotates immutability to me, perhaps a different method name would indicate changing one of the operands.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I think a `void Add` method could reasonably imply mutation.  I like your suggestion of changing the observed variable as well.

Answer (score 2):

First things first, as @D.Stanley notes, you can't override `+=`. You *can* override `+`, as you have done, but there is something important to realize about `+`:

> Math operators are non-destructive, that is, they return a result
>   without modifying the operands

That being said, you *could* modify the properties of operands in a reference type (which this is), but you *shouldn't*. So don't. The good news is, your `+` operation is correct.

Because of this, you have to return a `new` object (as you do), but when you do the `+=` you assign the local reference to this *new* object, while leaving the observer's reference pointing at the *old* object, causing your error.

You probably want to modify the observer directly:

```
showStats.statsToObserve += nextStats;
```

Or, you could totally hack it and do this (**not recommended**):

```
public static Stats operator +(Stats a, Stats b) {
    Stats c = new Stats();
    c.someField = a.someField + b.someField;
    a.SomeField += b.someField; //AHHHH You just modified an operand!
    c.someOtherField = a.someOtherField + b.someOtherField;
    a.someOtherField += b.someOtherField; //AHHHH You just did it again!
    return c;
}
```

Note: I like @DStanley's recommendation as well for the solution to this.